# How can I stop a gunicorn process on a server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, background-process

On my website I have this message "`Internal Server Error`". How can I kill a process in linux. so that I can run the proccess manually `/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 flaskodesiapp:create_app`

```
root@localhost:/flask_app_project# ps -A | grep gunicorn
  13210 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
  13212 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
  13215 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
  13216 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
root@localhost:/flask_app_project# sudo killall gunicorn3
root@localhost:/flask_app_project# ps -A | grep gunicorn
  13232 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
  13234 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
  13235 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
  13236 ?        00:00:00 gunicorn3
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/flask_app_project
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart= /usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 flaskodesiapp:create_app 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

supervisord  /etc/supervisor/conf.d/flask_app.conf

```
[program:flask_app]
directory=/flask_app_project
command=gunicorn3 --workers=3 flaskodesiapp:create_app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/flask_app/flask_app.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/flask_app/flask_app.out.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to stop supversisord first

```
ps -ef | grep supervisord
    root       12836       1  0 01:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
    root       13310   13127  0 02:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto supervisord
kill -s SIGTERM 12836
ps -ef | grep supervisord
    root       13325   13127  0 02:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto supervisord
sudo killall gunicorn3
```